# How to correct R Markdown Cookbook instructions on including icons?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I am working with R bookdown to test out the basic functionality of [including icons as is described in section 9.6.3 here from R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-blocks.html#block-image). Unfortunately, the R Markdown Cookbook instructions do not work for me when compiling the pdf, although the html does work just fine.

To create MWE use [this minimal example](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo).  Then according to the R Markdown Cookbook, change the preamble.tex file to be as follows.

```
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \makeatletter
 \def\thm@space@setup{%
   \thm@preskip=8pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
   \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip
 }
 \makeatother

 \usepackage{tcolorbox}

 \newtcolorbox{blackbox}{
   colback=black,
   colframe=orange,
   coltext=white,
   boxsep=5pt,
   arc=4pt}

 \newenvironment{infobox}[1]
   {
   \begin{itemize}
   \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{
     \raisebox{-.7\height}[0pt][0pt]{
       {\setkeys{Gin}{width=3em,keepaspectratio}
         \includegraphics{images/#1}}
     }
   }
   \setlength{\fboxsep}{1em}
   \begin{blackbox}
   \item
   }
   {
   \end{blackbox}
   \end{itemize}
   }
```

Change the style.css file according to the R Markdown Cookbook instructions as follows.

```
 p.caption {
   color: #777;
   margin-top: 10px;
 }
 p code {
   white-space: inherit;
 }
 pre {
   word-break: normal;
   word-wrap: normal;
 }
 pre code {
   white-space: inherit;
 }
 .blackbox {
   padding: 1em;
   background: black;
   color: white;
   border: 2px solid orange;
   border-radius: 10px;
 }
 .infobox {
   padding: 1em 1em 1em 4em;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   border: 2px solid orange;
   border-radius: 10px;
   background: #f5f5f5 5px center/3em no-repeat;
 }
 .warning {
   background-image: url("images/image_example.png");
 }
```

Now insert into the index.Rmd file the custom box instructions from R Markdown Cookbook.

```
 :::: {.infobox .warning data-latex="warning"}
 
 Include the actual content here.
 
 ::::
```

Note that inside the bookdown-demo-main folder, you also need to create an images subfolder with an image called image_example.png.  As far as I can tell, I have followed the cookbook instructions, but compiling to PDF using R command

```
 bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", "bookdown::pdf_book")
```

produces the error

```
 ! LaTeX Error: File `images/w' not found.
```

Notice that the knit button produces html just fine.  The icon appears as intended, and as demonstrated in the cookbook's instructions, for the html version of the book.  However, the pdf does not work.  I don't know how R produces the tex file.  Examination of the tex file itself does not help, because the custom box and image tex commands were not created in the first place in the pdf creation process executing by render_book.  I don't know how to more troubleshoot this.

Note that I am just trying to follow the instructions in R Markdown Cookbook.  Other of Cookbook's instructions have been great.  This is the first from the book that does not work for me.

Comment: Have you tried creating the HTML document, then use the "Print to PDF" option in the web browser to create a PDF, but retain the HTML format?

Comment: No, unfortunately "Print to PDF" cannot be used to create a book of publishable quality.  It does not replicate the typesetting and technical production given by a Latex backend.  (If that were true, the R bookdown package would be moot.). Thanks for taking the time to reply though, appreciate it.

Comment: I realized I should compile directly from the latex source and troubleshoot the desired preamble from there.  Still not sure of the solution but I will update again later if I figure it out